# How to DeSerialize String to Map using jackSon and gson libraries

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, gson

I have a class like this

```
@Data
public class A {
      private String aval1;
      private String aval2;

      private B b;//second class 
}
```

My B class is like this,

```
@Data
public class B {
      private String bval1;
      private String bval2;

      Map<String,String> errorLogs; 
}
```

For creation time i am sending setting that bclass values

```
Map<String, String> errorLogs = new HashMap<>();
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
B b = null;

b.setErrorLogs(errorLogs);
String metadata = objectMapper.writeValueAsString((Object) b);
workerJobBO.setMetadata(metadata);
```

After creation the values in database in like below ,

```
{
"aval1": "val1",
"aval2": "val2",  
"b": {
    "bval1": "val1",
    "bval2": "val2",
    "errorLogs": {
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2",
    "key3": "val3",
    "key4": "val4"      
    }
}
```

At the time of getting the values from services i am getting data like below,

```
[
 {
"aval1": "val1",
"aval2": "val2",
"b": {
    "bval1": "val1",
    "bval2": "val2",
    "errorLogs": {
        "entry": [{
            "key": "key1",
            "value": "val1"
        }, {
            "key": "key2",
            "value": "val2"
        }, {
            "key": "key3",
            "value": "val3"
        }, {
            "key": "key4",
            "value": "val4"
        }]
    }
 }
}
]
```

I have two layered structure to get data to client side.First Layer will be jersy restFul WebSerivices and Second layer will be Spring MVC structure

In first layer i am using jackson to convert,the above i am showing the output.

Second Layer Spring MVC i am using gson for deserialization purpose.
below i am showing how i am deserialising my code.using gson.

```
 ResponseEntity<String> out = restTemplate.exchange(Url, HttpMethod.POST, entity,
                String.class);

        Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<A>>() {
        }.getType();
        List<WorkerJobModel> jobs = gson.fromJson(out.getBody(),  collectionType);
```

I am getting on Error message in jason like this,

```
<body>
    <h1>HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 216 path $[0].pickupOrderDOM.errorLogs.</h1>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>
        <b>type</b> Exception report
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>message</b>
        <u>Request processing failed; nested exception is com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 216 path $[0].pickupOrderDOM.errorLogs.</u>
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>description</b>
        <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u>
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>exception</b>
    </p>
    <pre>org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 216 path $[0].pickupOrderDOM.errorLogs.
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

```
  </p>
    <pre>com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 216 path $[0].b.errorLogs.
com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:224)
com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852)
com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801)
com.zenxl.web.business.WorkerBO.getAllJobs(WorkerBO.java:53)
com.zenxl.web.controller.WorkerJobRestController.getJobsbyConsigner(WorkerJobRestController.java:33)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

**root cause**

```
    <pre>java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 216 path $[0].pickupOrderDOM.errorLogs.
com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextString(JsonReader.java:825)
com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$16.read(TypeAdapters.java:418)
com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$16.read(TypeAdapters.java:406)
com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:187)
com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852)
com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801)
com.zenxl.web.business.WorkerBO.getAllJobs(WorkerBO.java:53)
com.zenxl.web.controller.WorkerJobRestController.getJobsbyConsigner(WorkerJobRestController.java:33)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

AnyBody Can help me on this,

Thanks in Advance,

MadanMohan.Yaram

Comment: Have you created a public class and put your fields in there and put @SerializedName annotations in each fields ? you can also modify your variable for your convenience

Comment: for that i am using lombok jar so the public setter and getter are automatically generated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40621670/convert-json-to-map-entry-object-with-gson.Will this help you ?